# Output All Currency Values using PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to utilize the [Bitcoin Charts API](http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json) to display bitcoin value in all currencies as list items.

Currently I am repeating this PHP snippet in each list item:

```
<li class="myClass">
    <?php
        foreach(json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json")) as $item)
            if($item->symbol == 'localbtcPLN') break;
            printf("\t%s\nPLN", $item->avg);
    ?>
</li>
```

How can I simplify this so that the code is only calling the JSON file once?

Thanks for your help.

---

As per Vishal's assistance, I tried this:

```
 <?php $all_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json"),true);
    foreach ($all_data as $data)
        { 
        ?><li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-disabled">
        <?php
           echo $data['ask'];//use the keyname to get the value
           echo ' ';
           echo $data['currency'];
        ?>
        </li>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

However, it is outputting too much data, including empty values.

---

Using what I've learned from Florian and Vishal, I have attempted the following snippet, which outputted the data perfectly with the caveat of some duplicated currencies.

```
<?php $all_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json"),true);
                foreach ($all_data as $data)
                { 
                 if(trim($data['avg']) != "")//check if value not empty
                 {
                  ?><li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-disabled">
                    <?php
                        echo $data['avg']; //use the keyname to get the value
                        echo ' ';
                        echo $data['currency'];
                    ?>
                    </li>
                 <?php
                 }
                 }
              ?>
```

Comment: is it library which you are decoding?

Comment: @anant Sorry, I don't understand the question. :( It is just values from the JSON file I need to output.  In the above example the currency is "PLN".  I need to display all currencies without having to manually create this snippet for each.

Comment: then use a variable to stroe it (json decoded data)and use foreach on that variable.

Comment: @anant, I don't need to store it.  I just need to output it.

Comment: i mean to say assign this json_decode data to a variable and then use foreach loop on this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run a foreach loop

```
    <ol>
     <?php $all_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json"),true);
    foreach ($all_data as $data)
    { 
     if(trim($data['currency']) != "")//check if value not empty
     {
      ?><li>
        <?php echo $data['bid'];//use the keyname to get the value ?>
        </li>
     <?php
     }
     }
  ?>
    </ol>
```

Comment: thanks.  But where do I enter my HTML to structure the output?

Comment: thanks, however this is outputting far to much data.  I'm updating my question with what I used.

Comment: Vishal, I attempted it again with a revision of your newest update, but I am getting some of the currencies more than once.  Any idea why?

Comment: open this link http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json you will see that same currencies are repeated twice. so the code is perfect .. its the content over there which is repeated

Comment: Ah!  Thanks Vishal!  You've been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show values in a certain order.

First, store the result of json_decode() in an array like @Vishal Wadhawan said.

```
$all_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json"),true);
```

Next, make a new array where you will store only symbol and avg:

```
$myvalues = array();
foreach ($all_data as $data)
{
    $myvalues[$data['symbol']] = $data['avg'];
}
```

After that, you can use $myvalues to display avg like that:

```
<li class="myClass">    
    <?php echo $myvalues['localbtcPLN'] . ' PLN'; ?>
</li>
```

You can also store the 'currency' value:

```
$myvalues[$data['symbol']] = array(
                                    'avg' => $data['avg'],
                                    'currency' => $data['currency'],
);
```

And access it with:

```
<li class="myClass">    
    <?php echo $myvalues['localbtcPLN']['avg'] . ' ' . $myvalues['localbtcPLN']['currency']; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you Florian.  However, this seems like it will still force me to manually code each list item.  I'm looking to output all the list items automatically.

Comment: No, when you have your $myvalues array you can do a foreach loop on it: 

        <?php foreach ($myvalues as $value): ?>
               <li class="myClass">
                              <?php echo $value['avg'] . ' ' . $value['currency']; ?>
               </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: This didn't go so well for me Florian.  I am misunderstanding something.  However, I did get a very close output with my updated snippet based on direction from you and Vishal.